# Subband Tuning in Matlab

Tags: matlab, digital-filters, fast-convolution

Suppose you have an i/q stream with a sample rate of 20 MHz. You want to bandpass filter a 1 MHz bandwidth (ie passband from 5 to 6 MHz). You then want to heterodyne that 1 MHz chunk. How would you do this efficiently in matlab? Matlab's [bandpass](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/bandpass.html) function is really slow...

First idea that pops into my mind is to create a filter using [fir1](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/fir1.html) or [fir2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/fir2.html), then put the samples in a data [buffer](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/buffer.html) and then use [conv2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) or fft based convolution...

Comment: yes, that first idea sounds right. Have you tried it? sounds like a very small change...

Comment: @MarcusMüller wondering how you would unbuffer back to the 1D time series...